# Debit card issuance as a startup in Australia? Which SE site is appropriate to ask?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We are a currently trying to develop a payments product that requires debit card issuance as a core function, however in Australia there is no equivalent for Stripe or similar financial API product based businesses.

So we are seeking advice on how to get access to card issuance here, and potentially talk to PNO developers about other solutions to the problem we are trying to solve with card issuance.

Which SE site would be the most appropriate place to ask this type of question?

Comment: I doubt there will be any site that will take that question. It either is a recommendation type of question or too broad when you take the "talk to" part. Best bet is a chatroom.

Comment: Thank you for your response @rene - can you make a recommendation on a chatroom that we can jump into?

Comment: I have no recommendation to offer and even if I had, you've not yet reached the privilege that you can talk in chat. I'm sorry.